# How to validate username with rules

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set some rules for ma application username like min 3 characters and max 20 characters and only allow small case letter and numbers and only 2 special charters like . and _ that too only once. how can i do this.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions:

```
if(username.match(/^[a-z0-9_\.]{3,20}$/)==null) alert('Error!');
```